# Need to identify this Frame Please

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Need help identifying this frame, year and original spec please. It's a Giant TCR carbon frame. Frame number is GH1B037. Stickers in down tube Giant 3 but that's all I can get at the moment. Any help gratefully received. Want to return it to original spec

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Bike paint schemes are usually different for each component level and often change from year-year. I did a Google image search for 'Giant TCR Carbon' and looked through the results until I saw the exact match for the paint scheme on your bike.

It seems to be 2012 Giant TCR Advanced 3 as sold in the UK.

https://www.giant-bicycles.com/gb/tcr-advanced-3-2012

http://road.cc/content/review/58922-giant-tcr-advanced-3-2012

You will probably have trouble returning it to the *exact* component spec it was originally configured with as Giant used many in-house brand components (wheels, bars, post, stem in this instance; although you have the latter two) and the 2012 Shimano groupsets will not available, you will be able to outfit it with comparable level components of course.

Comment: You're welcome, can I get a check mark on my answer?

Comment: @Criggie thanks, I got lucky as I found a matching image very quickly, within a few minutes.